# Trying to remove a node from XML if it contains a child with a specific name but getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm building a small website to assist with modding Space Engineers Sandbox.sbc files in order to make inserting and removing mod ids easier.

I currently have the inserting of IDs working, but I'm having trouble with removing the mod xml element.

Here is the example code (the insert button works on my end but I wasn't sure how to correctly import the external javascript formatting plugin file).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insertmod").click(function() {
    var modID = $("#modID").val(),
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML($("#xmlTree").val()),
      $xml = $(xmlDoc),
      $mods = $xml.find("Mods");

    moditem = "<ModItem><Name>" + modID + ".sbm</Name><PublishedFileId>" + modID + "</PublishedFileId></ModItem>";
    $mods.append(moditem);

    prettyXML = $.format(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml[0]), {
      method: 'xml'
    });
    $("#xmlTree").val(prettyXML);
  });

  $("#removemod").click(function() {
    var modID = $("#modID").val(),
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML($("#xmlTree").val()),
      $xml = $(xmlDoc),
      $mods = $xml.find("Mods");

    $removalNode = $mods.filter("ModItem PublishedFileId:contains(" + modID + ")");
    $mods.remove($removalNode);

    prettyXML = $.format(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml[0]), {
      method: 'xml'
    });
    $("#xmlTree").val(prettyXML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/zachofalltrades/jquery.format/blob/master/jquery.format.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="modID">Mod ID
  <input type="text" name="modID" id="modID">
</label>
<br>
<label for="xmlTree">Current Sandbox.sbc XML
  <br>
  <textarea name="xmlTree" id="xmlTree" cols="30" rows="10">
    <Mods>
      <ModItem>
        <Name>302257706.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>302257706</PublishedFileId>
      </ModItem>
      <ModItem>
        <Name>303127240.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>303127240</PublishedFileId>
      </ModItem>
      <ModItem>
        <Name>301534203.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>301534203</PublishedFileId>
      </ModItem>
      <ModItem>
        <Name>300709199.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>300709199</PublishedFileId>
      </ModItem>
    </Mods>
  </textarea>
</label>
<br>
<button id="insertmod">Insert Mod</button>
<button id="removemod">Remove Mod</button>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

When I run my code to remove the xml element I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.replace is not a function      jquery.min.js:2
```

So I'm not even sure what's going on here because apparently somewhere in my code I broke jquery.

What my intention is: find the mods element. Next filter it to get at the modItem element that contains a child element which contains the text that matches the user's mod ID that they supplied. And then remove that element and display the resulting formatted xml, sans now removed moditem, to the textarea.

Comment: First: The Html is wrong, you must load BEFORE the jQuery then the format (based on jQuery). Second: I try your code but no error, can you post the step to repros.

Comment: Yes, both the path to the format-lib as well as the order in which you load them here (as @Max points out) was wrong. I've fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `find()` not `filter()` to remove XML nodes. As well you can't just do `ModItem PublishedFileId` to get the `ModItem` that has a `PublishedFileId` as child-node. Use `:has(...)` for this. Lastly, `$xml.remove(node)` should be `$xml.find('somePath').remove();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insertmod").click(function() {
    var modID = $("#modID").val(),
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML($("#xmlTree").val()),
      $xml = $(xmlDoc),
      $mods = $xml.find("Mods");

    moditem = "<ModItem><Name>" + modID + ".sbm</Name><PublishedFileId>" + modID + "</PublishedFileId></ModItem>";
    $mods.append(moditem);

    prettyXML = $.format(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml[0]), {
      method: 'xml'
    });
    $("#xmlTree").val(prettyXML);
  });

  $("#removemod").click(function() {
    var modID = $("#modID").val(),
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML($("#xmlTree").val()),
      $xml = $(xmlDoc),
      $mods = $xml.find("Mods");

    $mods.find("ModItem:has(PublishedFileId:contains('" + modID + "'))").remove();
    prettyXML = $.format(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml[0]), {
      method: 'xml'
    });
    $("#xmlTree").val(prettyXML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://zachofalltrades.github.io/jquery.format/jquery.format.js"></script>
<label for="modID">Mod ID
  <input type="text" name="modID" id="modID">
</label>
<br>
<label for="xmlTree">Current Sandbox.sbc XML
  <br>
  <textarea name="xmlTree" id="xmlTree" rows="20" style="width:100%">
  <Mods>
    <ModItem>
        <Name>302257706.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>302257706</PublishedFileId>
    </ModItem>
    <ModItem>
        <Name>303127240.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>303127240</PublishedFileId>
    </ModItem>
    <ModItem>
        <Name>301534203.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>301534203</PublishedFileId>
    </ModItem>
    <ModItem>
        <Name>300709199.sbm</Name>
        <PublishedFileId>300709199</PublishedFileId>
    </ModItem>
</Mods>
  </textarea>
</label>
<br>
<button id="insertmod">Insert Mod</button>
<button id="removemod">Remove Mod</button>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on both accounts.